# Best way to join 3 mySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery

I have a tag name and I need to fetch the tag id from the tags table then lookup all the ids that match the tag id in a taxonomy table and then fetch all the items that match the id in the taxonomy table. Can I do it all in 1 query or will I need a subquery? Here is an example of the database structure

```
tags database
tid, tag

tags taxonomy database
id, wid, tid

items databse
wid, *
```

I have the tag from the tags database I need to fetch the tid from the tags database then return all the wid's from the taxonomy database where the tid equals what we just fetched and then return * from the items database. I can get this done running 2 separate queries but I'm looking to do it in just 1. 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just `JOIN` the tables:

```
select *
from tags tg
left join taxonomy tx
    on tg.tid = tx.tid
left join items i
    on tx.wid = i.wid
```

If you are unfamiliar with `JOIN` syntax here is a good article:

[Visual Explanation of JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tags t
INNER JOIN taxonomy t2 ON t2.tid = t.tid
INNER JOIN items i ON i.wid = t2.wid
```

Note that this will return data only for rows that match in all 3 tables.